# Can we run an executable jar file inside an already running Kubernetes pod?

Tags: java, kubernetes, jar, executable-jar, kubernetes-pod

I need to execute a diagnostic program written for my application. The application is running/deployed in a Kubernetes pod. I want to copy a diagnostic executable jar file inside the Kubernetes pod and execute it without stopping the pod. How can this be achieved ? Is there a specific way to run the executable jar using the Kubernetes pod environment in place ?

Answer (score 5):

You can try the `kubectl cp` command:

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands):

> Copy /tmp/foo_dir local directory to /tmp/bar_dir in a remote pod in
> the default namespace

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir
```

> Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in a specific
> container

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-pod>:/tmp/bar -c <specific-container>
```

> Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace

```
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/bar
```

> Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

```
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

Once the executable is added inside the container, you can `exec` into the pod and execute the file manually.

Comment: My intent to ask the question was is it possible to run the executable jar file inside a Kubernetes pod and does really it works using the environment inside ? If yes, then is there a specific way to do it ? Copying the file inside the Kubernetes pod isn't an issue here. So, I am modifying the question a bit.

Comment: Once the executable is added inside the container, you can exec into the pod and execute the file manually.

Answer (score 1):

To open up interactive bash terminal

```
kubectl exec <pod name> -n <namespace> -c <container name> -it bash
```

After this, find your executable jar and run it. once completed, exit the terminal.

You can run it directly.

```
kubectl exec <podname> -n <namespace> -c <container name> -- < command to run your jar >
```

check this official k8s page https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec