# How do i view volumes attached to a container in a pod and write some data into it

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl, volume, kubernetes-pod

I want to write some data into volume i.e one of the directory which is residing in this volume, I can exec a pod, but i am not aware how to check the attached volume and write data to it.

I can find the volumes and mount point using:

```
kubectl describe pods pod-name
```

Comment: you can see the volumes attached to the pod using `kubectl describe` and `cd` to the directory after `exec` you want to write data to.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the volumes mounted on the pod using the output of `kubectl describe pod` which has the `Mounts` section in each container's `spec`.

An example from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/#using-kubectl-describe-pod-to-fetch-details-about-pods):

```
Mounts:
  /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5kdvl (ro)`
```

You can then `exec` into the pod using `kubectl exec` and the `cd` to the directory you want to write data to.

Another option is to use `kubectl copy` command and you could read a related answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66149037/can-we-run-an-executable-jar-file-inside-an-already-running-kubernetes-pod/66149285#66149285).

Answer (score 2):

1/ Access to the container console with this command:

```
kubectl exec <pod_name> --container <container_name> -n <namespace_name> --stdin --tty -- /bin/bash
```

- Replace <pod_name> by your pod name
- Replace <container_name> by you container name
- Replace <namespace_name> by the name of your namespace

2/ List mounted volumes with df command:

```
df
```

You'll see all container mounted volume